# Join split lines with specific character at the end of line

Tags: text-editing

I have to join two lines. One of them has point end of it to the previous one in whole text example:

```
line1:hello
line2:goodbye.
```

I need to change it to:

```
line1: hello goodbye.
```

I have to remove every 3rd line (multiples of 3, like 3,6,9,12,15,18,21,... lines) of this huge text.

This is what I want to do.

**First Task:**

- check every line
- if it ends with a period `.` go to the next line,
- if it doesn't end with period `.` join the next line to current line.

Each line doesn't have line number lable, they begin with normal words.

**Second Task**

- from the start every 3rd line is rubbish and should be removed
- the first task must also be done because in some parts the 3rd sentence is divided into 2 lines, so first I have to join the line completely which divided into 2 line then I perform the second task.

I use windows 7. I can use notepad++ and ultraedit

Answer (score 0):

**First task** I'd do in Notepad++, using regular expression search&replace:

- Open "Search" > "Replace..."
- As "Find what:", enter `"([^\.])\r\n"` (without the quotation marks)

  - Meaning of the Regex: Find a line that ends with something different than a "."
  - Note: If the document has Linux file endings, you must use just "\n" instead of "\r\n".
- As "Replace with:", enter `"\1 "` (without the quotation marks; make sure to also copy the space after "\1")
- As "Search Mode", select "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

Input:

```
hello
goodbye.
hello
hello
goodbye.
hello.
goodbye.
```

Output:

```
hello goodbye.
hello hello goodbye.
hello.
goodbye.
```

The **second task** can be done with an even longer regex:

- Open "Search" > "Replace..."
- As "Find what:", enter `"(([^\r\n]*\r\n){2})[^\r\n]*\r\n"` (without the quotation marks)

  - Meaning of the Regex: Find a block of three lines.
  - Note: Again, if the document has Linux file endings, you must use just "\n" instead of "\r\n".
- As "Replace with:", enter `"\1"` (without the quotation marks)
- As "Search Mode", select "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

Input:

```
hello goodbye.
hello hello goodbye.
sdlfj sdgf.
hello.
goodbye.
(/%&/$&=)?)=´?&%.
goodbye goodbye.
bye.
sldfjsdökl.
hello.
```

Output:

```
hello goodbye.
hello hello goodbye.
hello.
goodbye.
goodbye goodbye.
bye.
hello.
```

**Note:**
In both examples I assumed that there is no trailing whitespace. If there is, you'd need to strip that first, for example by regex-replacing (like above) `"\s*$"` with `""` (without the quotation marks).

Comment: Thank you so much for this big help,It does work, I didn't know it is possible to do with "Regular expression", I have to read about more, thanks a lot, ciao